# Best fish for a giant force of combat?

Tags: biology, warfare, combat

Alright, suppose that fish can breathe in the air. What species of fish, assuming there are 50,000 of them in a 10 year war against modern humans, would most likely prevail. The only conditions are that fish can breathe in the air, and other biological things such as mucus are all okay. Which fish, or group of fish, would be best for combat and mobility?

Edit: Fine, how about 10 BILLION fish, instead of 50,000.

Comment: What does it mean "a force of 50000"? We don't have stats like videogames..

Comment: None. No fish. They will all be slaughtered because they are overgrown mudskippers trying to fight a warlike and technologically advanced species on its home territory. Honestly, they sound pretty goddamn stupid. I guess the best fish would be one that tasted really bad, to reduce the humiliation of their utter defeat.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I think by "force", they mean "army", i.e. "an army of 50,000". Which, as Starfish noted, stands no chance against an army of 7.5 billion humans.

Comment: As L.Dutch commented. However I would go for candiru, the only good armour against them is adult diapers...

Comment: @user6760 they can't swim up a stream of urine through air. That's a ridiculous myth. And even if they could, the event is fatal to the fish, so that's a complete loss to the attacking force for 50000 humans hospitalised, most of whom are likely to survive.

Comment: You have edited, but your new numbers don't even come close to the most conservative estimates of the annual fish catch. Either way, my answer still stands.

Comment: A Land Shark could be deadly, especially if it can trick unwitting housewives by pretending to be a delivery man.   Bonus points if it has frickin' laser beams attached to its head.  Also, there is the ever-present threat of a sharknado, known to cause people in its proximity to be very bad actors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No chance.

There are fish who could defeat an *individual, surprised* human in the water. If they could breathe and walk on land, they might be able to defeat an *individual, surprised* human on land as well.

But humanity, as a whole, would have no problem to cope with 50,000 tyrannosaurus rex or 50,000 tigers. Supposedly humanity produced 3 million M2 heavy machine guns. Even allowing for most of them being junked over the century, there are plenty left to go big game hunting.

50,000 land-sharks or 50,000 land-orcas are no more problem.

Comment: Even in the water where their relative advantage is greatest, 50,000 sharks sounds more like an opportunity for fishing than a threat.

Comment: If the fish were, say, blue whales, and their means of attack was to fall upon their targets from great heights, they could target urban areas and kill many briefly surprised humans. And then think of the public health menace of a few million tonnes of exploded whale carcass in major cities...

Comment: @StarfishPrime, oh no, not again!

Answer (score 3):

## Like a fish out of water

There's a reason for that saying and it holds especially true for your scenario. 50,000 fish out of water for that matter, and what fish do out of water is flounder.

If you go too big they'll just be lying there like beached whales. Too small and we won't even notice.

The greatest effect your army of fish will have is when they start rotting and someone gets sick clearing up the bodies.

Answer (score 1):

**Greenland shark.**

1. They are blind because of parasites hanging off their eyes.  So they would fight using smell and sound like blind ninjas.
2. They are really big (30 feet) which is good if you are a blind ninja.
3. They live where it is really cold and hardly any people live.

[image: Greenland shark habitat]
https://www.sharksider.com/greenland-shark/

The war will take place in Qaanaaq, Greenland, population 656.

[image: qaanaaq]

I anticipate the war to be pretty short.  Once the Qaanaaq Supermarket falls, the remaining humans will retreat quickly.  Or maybe before that when they see 30 foot blind ninja sharks coming thru town.  The sharks will take over the town and surrounding area.  News of the shark war will reach other smaller towns in Greenland and allow the populace to escape before the sharks come.

There will not be a counterattack.  The sharks are uninterested in parts farther south but are themselves very interesting.  They will be observed from drones and helicopters, and eventually diplomats / scientists will attempt to communicate and make peace with our strange kin.

Answer (score 0):

**Blue Whales**

We'll have to handwave a few other things to give them the ability to move on land without instantly dying because a creature of their weight can only survive with the buoyancy water provides, and give them the ability to travel at a decent rate on land, but as long as we're giving them the ability to breathe air, we might as well do a little more to let them have a fighting chance. (Also, we're counting them as fish, even though technically they aren't. But they look like fish, they swim like fish, and they're in the ocean, so we can more or count them as fish. If not, just use whale sharks.)

With that said, blue whales are massive. They can weigh up to 150 tons, and can grow up to 80ft. long. At which point, they're basically just giant tanks which tear through whatever structure they're targeting. They can even try a few strategies, like burrowing through skyscrapers in an attempt to form a metal shield around themselves from the scrap catching on. (Not to mention that it'll give them greater damage with all that scrap iron. I mean, the iron weight around them will also kill them, but we're ignoring weight, so that's fine.)

So, that's your best chance for destroying mankind. Assemble your giant force out of giants, and proceed to destroy everything in your path with your giant arsenal of blue whales.

Still won't help against nukes, though.